# Disable clipping path from EPS with Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I have an EPS file from Photoshop with a clipping path on it:

[EPS File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjb7zeugy50x1kv/16212separata.eps)

I need to get a thumbnail from this file, so I have the following code:

```
$img = new imagick();                
$img->readimage($uploadfile);
$img->trimimage();
$img->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$img->scaleImage(200,200);
$img->writeimage($uploaddir . $thumb . ".jpg");
```

I get the following:

[Thumb bad](https://www.dropbox.com/s/04jr9rzzakw4qhf/thumb_bad.jpg)

Instead of what I need:

[Thumb ok](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vlcffvbl7cnwr6u/thumb_ok.jpg)

If I open the file on Photoshop and remove the path by hand I can see it ok, but I have around 3000 images like this, so I need to do this automatically.

Comment: I'd suggest getting this working with just the ImageMagick command line tool, rather than going through the PHP interface. Also, running `convert 16212separata.eps -strip -colorspace rgb separatenew.eps` should strip all clipping paths from your image, but there is none of the blue stuff present in your image.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with the CLI, but I don't think I could resolve this on the right way.

Comment: If you can't do it with the CLI, it's unlikely you can do it with Imagick.